# Django ORM Accessing related many-to-many objects through queryset

Tags: python, sql, django, orm

In my Django app, I have the following two models for events which can be given an arbitrary number of tags.

```
class Tag(models.Model):
  # ...

class Event(models.Model):
  # ...

  tags = models.ManyToManyField("Tag")
```

I also have a page where a user should be able to select a number of tags and then view all events associated with that tag. Given a list of tag IDs, can I use the Django ORM to get a list of (distinct) events associated with at least one of the given tags?

If not, I also tried achieving this with the following raw SQL

```
event.objects.raw("""
  SELECT *
  FROM   app_name_event_tags t
  WHERE  t.tag_id IN %s
""", selected_tag_ids)
```

There are two problems with this:

1) The events returned won't be distinct

2) My syntax for the placeholder for the list selected_tag_ids is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a list of `Tag` IDs, then you can get the related events by doing

```
Events.objects.filter(tags__id__in=selected_tag_ids).distinct()
```

Where `selected_tag_ids` is an iterable of integers (pks for `Tag` objects)

Further examples from the Django docs;

```
>>> Article.objects.filter(publications__id=1)
<QuerySet [<Article: Django lets you build Web apps easily>, <Article: NASA uses Python>]>

>>> Article.objects.filter(publications__title__startswith="Science")
<QuerySet [<Article: NASA uses Python>, <Article: NASA uses Python>]>

>>> Article.objects.filter(publications__title__startswith="Science").distinct()
<QuerySet [<Article: NASA uses Python>]>
```

Read my on Many-To-Many [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

to get the related events the easiest way is probably this:

```
list_of_tags = Tags.objects.filter(your condition)
events = Event.objects.filter(tags__in=list_of_tags).distinct()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I would accept your answer as well but it looks like I can only do one.